# GPO: Defining sites to local intranet zone - Does it overwrite existing sites defined?

Tags: group-policy, windows-domain

If I want to add a domain to local intranet sites in my entire network of +2000 computers and clients, does using GPO to do it potentially overwrite any existing defined sites on the clients?

We have lots of users who we've defined these local intranet sites manually on each client. And each client is usually a little different from the other one. But now I need to add a site that will apply for the entire network. I really want to avoid doing this manually if possible.

The specific GPO-settings I am asking about is located here:

*User Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Internet Explorer/Internet Control Panel/Security Page*

The object being *Site to Zone Assignment List*

Answer (score 1):

Creating that GPO will overwrite users settings and prevent them modifying settings

This may help you
https://blog.thesysadmins.co.uk/group-policy-internet-explorer-security-zones.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.